# Cannot return the record that match the condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table which contains a list of `match`:

```
id        |  datetime 
 2864049     2019-04-03 00:00:00
 2864050     2019-04-03 00:00:00
 2864051     2019-04-03 00:00:00
```

Essentially, I have to check if it exists and if it needs to be updated, for doing so I did:

```
SELECT mm.match_id
FROM (SELECT 2864049 as match_id, CAST("2019-04-03 00:00:00" AS DATETIME) AS match_datetime UNION ALL 
      SELECT 2864050 as match_id, CAST("2019-04-03 00:00:00" AS DATETIME) AS match_datetime UNION ALL 
      SELECT 2864051 as match_id, CAST("2019-04-03 00:00:00" AS DATETIME) AS match_datetime
     ) mm LEFT JOIN
     `match` m
     on m.id = mm.match_id AND m.datetime <> mm.match_datetime
WHERE m.id IS NULL
```

The problem is that this query shouldn't return any result, because all the three `match` exists, and also have the `datetime` field equal to the `matches` provided in the `mm` table.

The query need to return a result only if the `datetime` is different or if the `match` doesn't exist.

What I did wrong?

Comment: why don't you use [not exists](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-exists/)  features

Comment: @vishal but I also need to return the `matches` that need an update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the different date to where clause

Live test: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ee7ffb/1

```
CREATE TABLE `match`
    (`id` int, `datetime` datetime)
;

INSERT INTO `match`
    (`id`, `datetime`)
VALUES
    (2864049, '2019-04-03 00:00:00'),
    (2864050, '2019-04-03 00:00:00'),
    (2864051, '2019-04-03 00:00:00'),
    (2864052, '2019-04-03 00:00:00'),
    (2864053, '2019-04-03 00:00:00'),    
    (2864054, '2019-04-03 00:00:00')        
;



SELECT m.id, `datetime`
FROM 
`match` `m`
left join  
     (SELECT 2864049 as match_id, CAST("2019-04-03 00:00:00" AS DATETIME) AS match_datetime UNION ALL 
      SELECT 2864050 as match_id, CAST("2019-04-03 00:00:00" AS DATETIME) AS match_datetime UNION ALL 
      SELECT 2864051 as match_id, CAST("2019-04-03 00:00:00" AS DATETIME) AS match_datetime union all
      SELECT 2864052 as match_id, CAST("2019-04-04 00:00:00" AS DATETIME) AS match_datetime union all
      SELECT 2864054 as match_id, CAST("2019-04-03 00:00:00" AS DATETIME) AS match_datetime  
     ) mm 
     on m.id = mm.match_id 
WHERE 
mm.match_id IS NULL -- not existing
or m.datetime <> mm.match_datetime -- move to where clause
```

Output:

```
|      id |             datetime |
|---------|----------------------|
| 2864052 | 2019-04-03T00:00:00Z |
| 2864053 | 2019-04-03T00:00:00Z |
```

2864052 appears despite it has a matching id as its datetime is different from mm's

2864053 appears as it is not existing on mm

Answer (score 0):

try converting the date not using cast but STR_TO_DATE

```
SELECT mm.match_id
FROM (SELECT 2864049 as match_id, str_to_date("2019-04-03 00:00:00", '%Y-%m-%d %T' ) AS match_datetime 
      UNION ALL 
      SELECT 2864050 , str_to_date("2019-04-03 00:00:00", '%Y-%m-%d %T' )  
      UNION ALL 
      SELECT 2864051 , str_to_date("2019-04-03 00:00:00", '%Y-%m-%d %T' )
     ) mm 
LEFT JOIN  `match` m on m.id = mm.match_id AND m.datetime <> mm.match_datetime
WHERE m.id IS NULL
```

But you should check for you logic because you  are looking for a left join  for values that not match  ...  so if the row from mm table don't match the rows for m table you have a result for all these rows  with id null could be you need the left join for matching rows  eg:

```
SELECT mm.match_id
FROM (SELECT 2864049 as match_id, str_to_date("2019-04-03 00:00:00", '%Y-%m-%d %T' ) AS match_datetime 
      UNION ALL 
      SELECT 2864050 , str_to_date("2019-04-03 00:00:00", '%Y-%m-%d %T' )  
      UNION ALL 
      SELECT 2864051 , str_to_date("2019-04-03 00:00:00", '%Y-%m-%d %T' )
     ) mm 
LEFT JOIN  `match` m on m.id = mm.match_id AND m.datetime =  mm.match_datetime
WHERE m.id IS NULL
```

Comment: this also return all the records, noticed that in the `match` table all of these exists but doesn't need an update, so that's weird, the problem is on `m.datetime <> mm.match_datetime`, infact if I remove it no results is returned